# Difference between AbsoluteTiming and Timing

Tags: performance-tuning, evaluation, timing, function-comparison

I need to evaluate the efficiency of my code. Therefore I would like to evaluate the time the code need for some calculations. Mathematica gives me two possibilities for this kind of evaluation:

`AbsoluteTiming[expr]`

> evaluates expr, returning a list of the absolute number of seconds in real time that have elapsed, together with the result obtained.

`Timing[expr]`

> evaluates expr, and returns a list of the time in seconds used, together with the result obtained.

For both functions the Mathematica Documentation does not provide the section "Properties & Relations" which normally helps to find out the differences between two or more functions.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: You've read [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DateAndTimeFunctions.html#28423)?

Comment: I use `AbsoluteTiming` for everything. But opinions do differ here:)

Comment: @J.M. - something interesting - i noticed Timing[100000!;] is shown with "Second" in the output, whereas I dont see that on my machine's output

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Which one we use depends upon what we are trying to determine.  If our goal is to measure algorithmic time complexity, `Timing` (used carefully) is the tool.  If we want to measure how long a computation took to run in our environment, `AbsoluteTiming` is what we need.

`Timing` measures the amount of CPU time consumed by the kernel to evaluate a given expression.  The result is only approximate since, depending upon the underlying platform, it may or may not include CPU time used for system calls, page faults, process swaps, etc.  It will also not include any CPU time used by parallel processes and threads, even other Mathematica kernels.

`AbsoluteTiming` measures the amount of elapsed time (i.e. wall-clock time) to evaluate an expression.  Again, the result is approximate due to platform-specific overhead and clock resolution.

Let's look at some examples.

Let's try evaluating a computation-heavy expression across multiple kernels.  First, we'll measure the CPU time using `Timing`:

```
bigSum[n_] := Sum[RandomInteger[10]&[], {i, 1, n}]

SeedRandom[0]
ParallelTable[bigSum[i] // Timing, {i, {2^22, 2^23}}] // Timing
(* {0.015,{{2.98,20964693},{5.913,41923486}}} *)
```

We see that the master kernel racked up only 0.015 seconds of CPU time since it was spending most of its time twiddling its thumbs waiting for the subkernels to finish.  The two subkernels were busy though, using 2.98 and 5.913 seconds of CPU time each.  The total CPU time used for the entire computation was 0.015s + 2.98s + 5.913s = 8.908s.

Now let's measure the same computation using `AbsoluteTiming` to get the elapsed time:

```
SeedRandom[0]
ParallelTable[bigSum[i] // AbsoluteTiming, {i, {2^22, 2^23}}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {5.9904000,{{2.9952000,20982605},{5.9592000,41944028}}} *)
```

We see that the first subkernel was done in 2.995s of elapsed time.  The second subkernel needed 5.959s.  The master kernel took just a little bit longer since it had to assemble the results, running for 5.990s.  Unlike CPU time, these quantities do not add so the total elapsed time for the expression was the largest, 5.990s.

We can contrast these results with those from a computation that is not CPU intensive:

```
ParallelTable[(Pause[i*5];i) // Timing, {i, 1, 2}] // Timing
(* {0.,{{0.,1},{0.,2}}} *)
```

This time we see that, for practical purposes, none of the kernels used any CPU time.  They did, however, take real time to execute:

```
ParallelTable[(Pause[i*5];i) // AbsoluteTiming, {i, 1, 2}] // AbsoluteTiming
(*{11.7624000,{{5.0076000,1},{10.0152000,2}}}*)
```

From these results we can see that `Timing` is valuable when we are trying to determine the CPU load of a computation.  This measure has a strong correlation to the time complexity of an algorithm, provided we take care to track the CPU time in *all* relevant processes.

`AbsoluteTiming` is valuable when we don't really care about CPU resource usage or time complexity, but are primarily interested in how long a computation will take (to know whether we should take a coffee break or a vacation while we wait).  It can also be useful to estimate computational cost of external processes that we cannot monitor directly (e.g. protected system processes or remote machines).

Beware that neither `Timing` nor `AbsoluteTiming` will account for time taken to render any computed results in the front end:

```
Format[slowRender[]] := Null /; (Pause[5]; False)

slowRender[] // Timing // AbsoluteTiming
(* {6.15813*10^-6, {0., slowRender[]}} *)
```

The kernel code that measures timing is unaware of the activities of the front end.  Rendering time can be significant for large amounts of result data or for complex visualizations.

**Update, 2015**

The examples in this response were written in 2012 using *Mathematica* version 8 on Windows.  As noted in [Incorrect Timing of Total](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98453/142), version 10.3 offloads more processing to subsidiary threads whose CPU time cannot be tracked using `Timing` (nor `AbsoluteTiming` presuming there is more than one thread).  Be aware of the possibility of such behaviour when the goal is to account for all CPU time consumed.

The documentation pages for both `Timing` and `AbsoluteTiming` allude to this problem:

> On certain computer systems with multiple CPUs, the Wolfram Language kernel may sometimes spawn additional threads on different CPUs. On some operating systems, [`Timing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Timing.html) may ignore these additional threads. On other operating systems, it may give the total time spent in all threads, which may exceed the result from [`AbsoluteTiming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteTiming.html).

Comment: WReach, I felt [this Q&A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98453/4330) about a misleading result of `Timing` when used to time `Total` is very relevant. Note the difference between Windows and OSX. Also, you example `ParallelTable[(Pause[i*5]; i) // Timing, {i, 1, 2}] // Timing` evaluates to `{1.10491,{{0.116654,1},{0.268138,2}}}` for me on OSX mma 10.3, which seems to be fundamentally different from your result. Considering the specific knowledge that goes into this, would you consider expanding your note "(used carefully)"?

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom I have added a new section that makes the difficulty of measuring CPU time more explicit, with a reference to the Q&A you linked.  I do not have access to _Mathematica_ on OSX.  It may be just coincidence with only two data points, but the times reported are proportional to the `Pause` duration (at about 2% CPU/real time, a surprisingly large ratio).  I wonder if this overhead is real, or if it is just an artifact of measurement and/or threading?

Comment: WReach, thanks for your edit, I like it. I did some more timings and there indeed seems to be 2% overhead, proportional to the `Pause` duration. I can only guess at the answer of whether there is a real overhead. Note that you can abort a `Pause`. Maybe the kernel thread does not go to sleep any time a `Pause` is called, but rather it goes into some kind of waiting loop. I wonder if an abort signal is really an OS level signal, or whether it is a mathlink thing. Maybe Halirutan or Szabolcs know more.

Comment: @WReach, is it possible to measure both `Timing` and `AbsoluteTiming` for an expression?

Comment: @alancalvitti We can write `expr // Timing // AbsoluteTiming` to get both.  The `AbsoluteTiming` result will include the real time taken by the `Timing` call, but that will be insignificant in practice.

Comment: @WReach, thanks. But why does AbsoluteTiming return a smaller value than Timing here: `Table[RandomInteger[100], {10000}, {10000}]; // 
  Timing // AbsoluteTiming`  --> {5.32969, {4.91461, Null}}

Comment: @alancalvitti As noted in the documentation of `Timing`, it does not track all CPU time.  In your example, `RandomInteger` appears to involve untracked operations.  Perhaps it calls out to an external library, or uses an OS thread.  Or perhaps there are lots of page faults or non-trivial garbage collection activity when growing a 10000 x 10000 array.  (Note: the `AbsoluteTiming` value is larger than the `Timing` value in the example).

Comment: @WReach, thanks, I got the ordering backward b/c of nesting.

Comment: @WReach Please consider mentioning a typesetting and a rendering stage for completeness.

Comment: @Kuba Done.  I have inserted a short discussion immediately prior to the _Update, 2015_ section.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 35):

I used to use `Timing[]` for all my performance evaluations ... and have completely stopped doing so ... I now use `AbsoluteTiming[]` for everything. The reason for my switch is predominantly the advent of parallel processors and multiple kernels.

If you evaluate on a multiprocessor machine:

```
 Timing[  blah ]
```

... Mathematica returns the time taken for ONLY the master kernel to issue the instruction to the slave kernels and manage them ... which might be 0.01 seconds;  the slaves might spend an hour each on the calculation, but the timing taken by the master kernel is 0.01 seconds and that is what is reported back to you. In other words, `Timing[]` in a multiprocessor environment has become highly misleading and largely pointless. It is not the timing function you generally want.

So, I now use `AbsoluteTiming` for everything!  It does what you expect `Timing` to do. For me, `Timing` is to be avoided.