# What could cause Timing to report erroneously?

Tags: timing

I am using `Timing` to measure the time it takes to load a ".dat" file and the reported time (4.47 seconds) is waaaay below the real time (measured using a stopwatch on my phone) which is about 44 seconds. I've never encountered such behaviour and I find it quite confusing. What could be the reason behind this and how to fix it?

Comment: What does `AbsoluteTiming` give? I think `Timing` measures kernel time only, so for example if you're trying to "display" the data in its entirety in Mathematica front end, that can take a long time to render but won't be included in `Timing`. Not sure that's what is happening here, but perhaps something like that.

Comment: Apparently the truth! I am going to use AbsoluteTiming from now on then, and the explanation is probably lying somewhere in what you're saying. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: "[`Timing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Timing.html) includes only CPU time spent in the Wolfram Language kernel. It does not include time spent in external processes connected via WSTP or otherwise. Nor does it include time spent in the Wolfram System front end."

Comment: It is mentioned in the "Details" section of the documentation on timing (@Bob's quote).

Comment: Is that enough for an answer?: [Difference between AbsoluteTiming and Timing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14152/5478)