# Incresing efficiency of the code:

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning

I have a set of points, representing location of events in a map, and I want to find the closest neighbour for each point. Variable `xys` is a 2D matrix containing the set of coordinates for each point (column 1 for x- and column 2 for y-coordinate).

```
xys = Table[RandomReal[{1, 9000}], {rr, 1, 300}, {cc, 1, 2}]
```

To calculate the distance I come up with two approaches:

Approach 1

```
Table[ ArcLength[Line[{xys[[jj]], xys[[ii]]}]], {ii, 1, Length[xys]}, {jj, 1, Length[xys]}]
```

> {21.8557, Null}

Approach 2

```
Table[Sqrt[(xys[[1, 1]] - xys[[ii, 1]])^2 + (xys[[1, 2]] - xys[[ii, 2]])^2], {ii, 1, 1000}];
```

> {0.468003, Null}

Approach 1 quite inefficient: for calculating 300 points, it takes 21 sec. Approach 2 is almost two order of magnitude faster, at 0.4 sec.

What I would like to understand is why is there such a big difference. I thought ArcLength[Line[...]] would be the faster and more efficient since it uses Mathematica functions. Since my real data set ultimately will be 10000-30000 points, the whole process will end up to be quite long even with the second approach. Therefore I would be grateful if anyone could suggest an even more efficient and faster approach.

Thanks,

Comment: You may also be interested in [Nearest](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest.html), [GeoNearest](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoNearest.html), [NearestNeighborGraph](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NearestNeighborGraph.html) and other built in functionality.

Comment: If the desire is to get the geographical distances, fastest is to use `Nearest` (as noted by others) with Euclidean distance, and postprocess to get geodistances between relevant pairs. This will work correctly if all points are in the same hemisphere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reading the documentation of [ArcLength](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcLength.html), it seems to perform an integration to determine the length of an arbitrarily complex arc. It is therefore written to support **much more complex shapes** than simple point-to-point lines and is simply oversized for your purpose.

The built-in function you are probably looking for is `EuclideanDistance`, which is about two orders of magnitude faster than `ArcLength`:

```
ArcLength[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]] // RepeatedTiming // ScientificForm
EuclideanDistance[{0, 0}, {1, 0}] // RepeatedTiming // ScientificForm
```

> {2.0*10^(-4), 1}
>
> {4.97*10^(-6), 1}

As for the faster solutions, they have already been stated in the comments and answers. `Nearest` is usually the fastest way to do such tasks. By the way, when constructing a [DistanceMatrix](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistanceMatrix.html) as suggested by @kglr, it also uses `EuclideanDistance` as the default `DistanceFunction` for numerical data.

Answer (score 8):

```
xys = RandomReal[{1, 9000}, {10, 2}] 
DistanceMatrix[xys] //MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\tiny\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccccc}
>  0. & 2811.96 & 1448.01 & 4793.19 & 4974.56 & 3210.02 & 3812.18 & 4829.63 & 3786.22 & 4540.3 \\
>  2811.96 & 0. & 2223.34 & 7489.06 & 2545.11 & 5986.82 & 6588.37 & 4435.52 & 6566.55 & 1979.34 \\
>  1448.01 & 2223.34 & 0. & 6082.27 & 3805.6 & 4428.17 & 5014.48 & 5624.91 & 4980.33 & 4194.48 \\
>  4793.19 & 7489.06 & 6082.27 & 0. & 9767.75 & 1683.23 & 1176.8 & 7061.33 & 1226.24 & 8869.71 \\
>  4974.56 & 2545.11 & 3805.6 & 9767.75 & 0. & 8164.34 & 8762.34 & 6654.91 & 8732.36 & 2983.62 \\
>  3210.02 & 5986.82 & 4428.17 & 1683.23 & 8164.34 & 0. & 602.571 & 6362.66 & 579.835 & 7528.06 \\
>  3812.18 & 6588.37 & 5014.48 & 1176.8 & 8762.34 & 602.571 & 0. & 6798.88 & 53.2738 & 8113.77 \\
>  4829.63 & 4435.52 & 5624.91 & 7061.33 & 6654.91 & 6362.66 & 6798.88 & 0. & 6812.2 & 3916.62 \\
>  3786.22 & 6566.55 & 4980.33 & 1226.24 & 8732.36 & 579.835 & 53.2738 & 6812.2 & 0. & 8100.6 \\
>  4540.3 & 1979.34 & 4194.48 & 8869.71 & 2983.62 & 7528.06 & 8113.77 & 3916.62 & 8100.6 & 0. \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
Nearest[xys -> {"Index", "Element", "Distance"}, xys, 2][[All, 2]]
```

> {{3, {4186.12, 3056.38}, 1448.01},
>   {10, {126.15, 4110.1}, 
>     1979.34},
>   {1, {4655.43, 4426.22}, 1448.01},
>   {7, {7903.7, 6421.58}, 
>     1176.8},
>    {2, {2004.91, 3487.15}, 2545.11},
>    {9, {7905.61, 6368.34}, 
>     579.835},
>   {9, {7905.61, 6368.34}, 53.2738},
>   {10, {126.15, 4110.1}, 
>     3916.62},
>   {7, {7903.7, 6421.58}, 53.2738},
>   {2, {2004.91, 3487.15}, 
>     1979.34}}

Answer (score 4):

These are the tests and timings of different approaches, and lastly what I think is the best implementation

```
xys = Table[RandomReal[{1, 9000}], {rr, 1, 1000}, {cc, 1, 2}];

dist = Table[EuclideanDistance[xys[[ii, 1]], xys[[jj, 1]]], {ii, 1, Length[xys]}, {jj, 1, Length[xys]}]; // Timing

dist = DistanceMatrix[xys]; // Timing
```

> {1.38841, Null}
>
> {0.0312002, Null}

The `EuclideanDistance` is indeed the right function, as *Theo Tiger* has nicely explained. However, the inbuilt function `DistanceMatrix` is 1-2 order of magnitude faster. Therefore, `DistanceMatrix` appears to be the better option for calculating all distance between points and generate a matrix.

```
Flatten[Table[TakeSmallest[dist[[ii, All]], 11][[2 ;; 11]], {ii, 1, Length[dist]}]]; // Timing

Flatten[Table[Sort[dist[[ii, All]]][[2 ;; 11]], {ii, 1, Length[dist]}]]; // Timing
```

> {0.0780005, Null}
>
> {0.156001, Null}

For finding the first nearest object(s), `Sort` is a good way, but my test I found that `TakeSmallest` is an even better approach.
In conclusion `DistanceMatrix` and `TakeSmallest` are the one I used for my solution and I when I computed to find the 10 closest neighbors' distances for 10 sets of 10000 points each, it took mere seconds

```
Table[
xys = RandomReal[{1, 9000}, {10000, 2}];

dist[rr] = DistanceMatrix[xys];

nearneighbor[rr] = 
Flatten[Table[ 
  TakeSmallest[dist[rr][[ii, All]], 11][[2 ;; 10]], {ii, 1, 
   Length[dist[rr]]}]];

, {rr, 1, 10}]; // Timing
```

> {3.47882, Null}

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: You may be interested in the [Difference between Timing and Absolute Timing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14152/difference-between-absolutetiming-and-timing).

Comment: A variation on @kglr's, `Nearest[xys -> "Distance", xys, 10]`, does the last task in under `0.1` sec. on laptop. (Note it returns ten distances, but the span `2 ;; 10`in your code will yield only nine.  I suspect it's typo and you meant to write `2 ;; 11`.  You can also get the same effect with `Rest@TakeSmallest[..]`)