# Why do I keep getting the same time from the Timing function?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, timing

I am running a gamblers problem solution where I am testing the timing involved in solving the Ax = b equation for matrices of n=100, 1000, 10000, and 100000. For some reason I keep getting the same time (0.015625 seconds) for the time, but I know it takes many more seconds than this. The matrix for n=100000 ran for probably 20 mins and still returned 0.015625.

My process to create the matrix is basically:

```
 A = IdentityMatrix[100000, SparseArray];
 For[i = 2, i < 100000, i++,
 A[[i, i]] = -1;
 A[[i, i - 1]] = .5;
 A[[i, i + 1]] = .5
 ];
```

The vector is created by:

```
b = {1};
For[i = 2, i <= 100000, i++, b = Insert[b, 0, -1] ];
```

Then I run:

```
Timing[LinearSolve[A, b]]
```

Comment: What are `matrixSize`, `vectorSize` and `coefficientMatrix`?

Comment: Sorry, I removed those variables.

Comment: What happens if you use `AbsoluteTiming` instead of `Timing`?

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14152/difference-between-absolutetiming-and-timing

Comment: AbsoluteTiming doesn't  give me the same number anymore, yet it still gives a very small number.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot tell what the problem with the timing is but I can show you how to set up and solve the system quicker:

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[
 n = 100000;
 A = SparseArray[{
  Band[{1, 1}] -> -1., 
  Band[{2, 1}] -> 0.5, 
  Band[{1, 2}] -> 0.5
  }, 
  {n, n}];
 b = Normal[SparseArray[{1} -> 1., {n}]];
 x = LinearSolve[A, b];
 ]
```

> 0.665885