# How to select the fastest approach for large numerical data computations?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, numerics, pattern-matching, functional-style

I really love the flexibility of `Mathematica`: there are several ways to perform one task. However, to get the performance of the intense numeric calculation, it can cause some confuses. I wonder is it the real strength or the weakness of the language.

**Example:** Take a list of the first element in a matrix.

```
test1 = Transpose[{Range[10^8], Range[10^8]}];
```

The input list is Packed Array.

```
Developer`PackedArrayQ[test1]
True
```

For this simple task, there **are many ways** to do that. Now guess the performance of these commands:

```
(* test1 /. {a_, _} -> a; // Timing *) (* WARNING: May lock up your Mathematica! *)
First /@ test1; // Timing
test1[[All, 1]]; // Timing
Transpose[test1][[1]]; // Timing
First[Transpose[test1]]; // Timing
Take[Transpose[test1], 1]; // Timing
```

I think that, *"Oh, the third one which uses only one function `Part`. This one should be the fastest"*. The rule of thumb, is:

- Use lesser function will improve the speed
- Treat the data as the whole
- Use built-in function
- Use packed array, etc
- Avoid using Patterns for numerical calculation

So `test1[[All, 1]]` should be the fastest. But no, I'm wrong.

---

**Timing results:**

The slowest solution is:

```
test1 /. {a_, _} -> a; // Timing
```

Don't run this, because Mathematica will be stuck. (**I need to Abort the Evaluation**). It's obvious because Pattern searching and replacement are expensive. Luckily I didn't often use this type of programming.

The next slow solution is:

```
First /@ test1; // Timing

{2.90625, Null}
```

Surprisingly, `Part` is the next slow solution. I wonder why? This is the only case that uses one function `Part`.

```
test1[[All, 1]]; // Timing
{1.21875, Null}
```

And the combinations of 2 functions approaches are faster. `Transpose` and then `Part`, `First` and `Transpose`, `Take` and `Transpose`.

```
Transpose[test1][[1]]; // Timing
First[Transpose[test1]]; // Timing
Take[Transpose[test1], 1]; // Timing


{0.765625, Null}

{0.734375, Null}

{0.609375, Null}
```

The main question here is, there are too many approaches to perform the same operation. And normally, I didn't know which approach is the most optimal way in terms of efficiency.

Comment: It can depend on the system, but [`AbsoluteTiming`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14152/difference-between-absolutetiming-and-timing) or `RepeatedTiming` may be better tools to measure performance than `Timing`.

Comment: I'm not sure what the real question is here. The behaviors exhibited are exactly what one would expect. Perhaps try your experiment using non-square matrices for further illumination.

Comment: @ciao I don't share your opinion that this is expected. Personally, I'd expect `Part` to have the best performance here because it's the idiomatic way to do things and I'd expect internal optimizations to be in place for this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The main question here is, there are too many approaches to perform the same operation. And normally, I didn't know which approach is the most optimal way in terms of efficiency.

Mathematica's performance is hard to predict, even more so than that of other high-level languages. There is no simple guideline you can follow. There will always be surprises and the behaviour will change from one version to the next.

---

Some insight into why `Transpose` is faster here:

On my machine (macOS  / M12.1) `Timing` reports the lowest numbers for `Part`, not for `Transpose`. However, `RepeatedTiming` (which is based on `AbsoluteTiming`) reports a lower number for `Transpose`.

```
In[16]:= test1[[All, 1]]; // Timing
Out[16]= {1.32521, Null}

In[17]:= test1[[All, 1]]; // RepeatedTiming
Out[17]= {1.41, Null}

In[18]:= First[Transpose[test1]]; // Timing
Out[18]= {2.08334, Null}

In[19]:= First[Transpose[test1]]; // RepeatedTiming
Out[19]= {0.80, Null}
```

Typically, this is an indication that some operations are done in parallel. `Timing` measures the total time spent by each CPU core, while `AbsoluteTiming` measures wall time.

A quick look at the CPU monitor confirms that indeed, `Part` is single threaded (I see 100%) while `Transpose` is multi-threaded (I see ~250%).

This explains the difference.

Comment: Oh. Thank you. I forget about the multi-threaded too.

Comment: Whether `Part` should or shouldn't be multithreaded—that's debatable. I disabled multithreading and benchmarked this again, and on my machine at least, and with this specific size of array, `Transpose` is still very slightly faster than `Part`.

Comment: @NamNguyen I don't know the state of the art of `Transpose` at Wolfram, but transposing tensors is a highly researched and important operation. Solutions exist that take account of the available cores and cache. In a large-memory problem, memory management is likely to be a major factor. On an Intel machine, `Transpose` probably calls the MKL routine [`mkl_?imatcopy`](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/mkl-developer-reference-fortran/top/blas-and-sparse-blas-routines/blas-like-extensions/mkl-imatcopy.html). As Szabolcs said, though, these things change over time

Comment: Thank you very much @MichaelE2.

Comment: I also prefer using `Range` over `Table`. The only reason I use `Table` is for this: `Table[x, {4}]`, because I didn't know another function to generate a list of Symbol like this.

Answer (score 4):

This is another observation, that sometimes in Mathematica, combining 2 functions is faster than using 1 function.

Jon McLoone " 10 Tips for Writing Fast Mathematica Code " has proposed that "Using fewer function will speed up". But not all the case, I think.

Do a simple test: Using a function inside a `Table` to generate list.

```
In[11]:= a1 = Table[Power[i, 2], {i, 10^7}]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[11]= {0.238681, Null}
```

Using Range first, and then put it in a functions .

```
In[12]:= a2 = Power[Range[10^7], 2]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[12]= {0.0703124, Null}
```

Both are PackedArray.

```
In[16]:= Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ {a1, a2}

Out[16]= {True, True}
```

Maybe, `Part`, and `Table` are the big function? So they need to check something before doing the computational code? And `Range`, and `Transpose` is faster, because they are just doing one simple thing with less overhead?

**Conclusions**

- Don't use Table[f,{i,iMax}]
- But use f[Range[iMax]]

here is the performance proof:

```
testTable[n_] := AbsoluteTiming[Table[Power[i, 2], {i, 10^n}];]
testRange[n_] := AbsoluteTiming[Power[Range[10^n]];]

nList = {4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

t1 = First@testTable[#] & /@ nList;
t2 = First@testRange[#] & /@ nList;

ListLinePlot[{Transpose[{nList, t1}], Transpose[{nList, t2}]}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Table", "Range"}, Mesh -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, basically use vectorization whenever you can.